# Passing an enum value to a template extension method in Quarkus-Qute

Tags: java, templates, extension-methods, quarkus, quarkus-qute

I have following template extension:

```java
package com.company;

import io.quarkus.qute.RawString;
import io.quarkus.qute.TemplateExtension;

@TemplateExtension
public class TemplateExtensions {

    static RawString myMethod(Input input, String someEnumName) {
        SomeEnum value = SomeEnum.valueOf(someEnumName);
        //...
        return new RawString("...");
    }
}
```

With this enum:

```java
package com.company;

public enum SomeEnum {
    LOREM,
    IPSUM;
}
```

In my template I do following:

```
{input.myMethod('LOREM')}
```

This works great, but I am wondering how and if I can use the enum value directly:

```java
package com.company;

import io.quarkus.qute.RawString;
import io.quarkus.qute.TemplateExtension;

@TemplateExtension
public class TemplateExtensions {

    static RawString myMethod(Input input, SomeEnum value) {
        //...
        return new RawString("...");
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
{input.myMethod(com.company.SomeEnum.LOREM)}
```

But this creates:

```
NOT_FOUND
```

---

Hello resource:

```java
package com.company;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import io.quarkus.qute.Template;
import io.quarkus.qute.TemplateInstance;

@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {

    @Inject
    Template helloTemplate;

    @GET
    @Path("/index.html")
    public TemplateInstance index() {
        return helloTemplate.data("input", new Input());
    }
}
```

And Input Class:

```java
package com.company;

public class Input {
    String foo = "bar";

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this too, and I found an answer by searching through the Github issues for Quarkus. You can do it with [Template Extensions](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#template_extension_methods)

Add a method like this to your Enum:

```java
    @TemplateExtension(namespace = "SomeEnum", matchName = ANY)
    static SomeEnum getVal(String val) {
        return SomeEnum .valueOf(val.toUpperCase());
    }
```

and then in your template, you can access it using `{SomeEnum:LOREM}`